# Quick Confirmation of Fourier series using trigonometric identities

Tags: fourier-series

The Fourier series expansion  for $f(x) = \sin 5x \sin x$ is $\dfrac{\cos 4x - \cos 6x}{2}$? This makes sense as $f(x) = \sin 5x \sin x$ is made up of the product of two odd functions which equals an even function and hence why there are are no sine functions in the answer.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $x,y \in \mathbb R$, we have by the addition formulae for the cosine:
$$ \cos(x \pm y) = \cos x \cos y \mp \sin x \sin y 
$$
Subtracting, we get
$$ \cos(x+y) - \cos(x-y) = -2 \sin x \sin y $$
Now let $y = 5x$, to obtain
$$ \cos(6x) - \cos(4x) =- 2 \sin x \sin 5x $$

Comment: Does that mean that the fourier expansion is incorrect or just my reasoning?

Comment: I thought and interpreted the title that you asked for a reasoning using trigonometric identities. You are correct, I have a typo, which I will correct.

Comment: Oh yeah I see, sorry about that. Thanks